# Discord.py Bot Error | Roblox API Python | No error No message, How do I fix?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roblox

I wanted to make when you type !tags the discord bot searches for tags by API in random popularity clothes, but when I type `!tags` it doesn't send any error, any message in discord. Is there any fixes and can I improve the code?

The full code:

```py
code REMOVED
```

Could you help and explain if you can, if you cant explain just please try making my code better.

I tried but it just doesn't give me error or any message the bot.

Comment: I would suggest printing all `response` to see if the URL is even valid and what it's looking for

Comment: Add `discord.utils.setup_logging()` bellow your bot definition to enable the logs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your second api request in `get_shirt_description` function. It is invalid to format it like `f"https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/catalog/items/details?id={item_id}"`. So, it will return your some json like

```json
{
  "errors":[{
    "code":0,
    "message":"MethodNotAllowed"
  }]
}
```

Then in this scenario, your `any(keyword in description for keyword in keywords)` in `contains_tags` will always return `False` back to the if statement. So, there is not any error but also not executing any line under your if statement.
Rather than this, You need to send a `json` with your POST method request to `https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/catalog/items/details`. Something like

```py
item_json = {
  "items": [{
    "itemType": 1,
    "id": 12222721460
  }]
}

response = requests.post(
  url="https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/catalog/items/details", 
  json=item_json, 
  headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": Your_Token
  }
)
# print(response.json())
# do sth further
```

See more [docs](https://catalog.roblox.com/docs/index.html#!/Catalog/post_v1_catalog_items_details) 
Also, I would strongly suggest you to switch `requests` to `aiohttp` since `requests` module is blocking.

Comment: Hello I still don't get anything, my code is

Comment: cookie = "MY_ROBLOX_COOKIE"

async def get_shirt_description(session, item_id):
    api_url = "https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/catalog/items/details"
    item_json = {
        "items": [
            {
                "itemType": 1,
                "id": item_id
            }
        ]
    }

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cookie": cookie
    }

Comment: async with session.post(api_url, json=item_json, headers=headers) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            data = await response.json()
            if "data" in data:
                item_data = data["data"][0]
                description = item_data.get("description", "")
                return description
    return None

Comment: @TermuxUser I believe it only needs X-CSRF-TOKEN and if the token is missing or in incorrect format, it will basically return you a 403, which means they block you from getting the data you want. Otherwise, the API endpoint should work fine

Comment: You're right, i had to make automatic x-csrf-token extractor from auth.roblox.com and it now works perfectly, I have debugged my code and found that error. Thank you for help! :)